# Is it possible to add a light cookie via script at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that creates a spot light in unity when ran. Is it possible to add a light cookie via script using light.cookie or something along those lines?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript] and this isn't a proper use of the [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, looking at the scripting reference you access 'cookie' of your light instance.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light-cookie.html